# Closed curve from segments

Tags: matlab, image-processing, shapes

I have an image with a set of curve segments (below) and I would like to somehow get the corresponding close curve. Do you have any suggestion on how to approach the problem? Thanks! I am working in Matlab.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
output=imclose(image,fspecial('disk',150));
```

Creates a contour that works for this image.  A general solution depends on the types of inputs possible.

Answer (score 1):

In case it might be helpful, this is the code I ended up using:

```
SE = strel('disk',10);
IM2 = imerode(imfill(imdilate(image,SE)), SE);
```